# I am getting null in my payload because of late redux form store update

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am conditionally changing one of my values in redux store and calling an API right after that.
But that value is still null by the time API response is pending.
How can I call API having that value in my payload?

(I am using redux form)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
        if(amount <= SMALL_AMOUNT){
            props.changeFormValue('term', 50);
        }
      
    }, [props, amount]);

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    const getSecuredLoanValues = async({
        termValue= _get(formValues, 'term', null),
        ....
        ....
      }) => {

        const payload= {
            term_in_months: termValue,
             ....
             ....
        };
     ....
     ....
    }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   <Field
       name="term"
       component={Terms}
       label="TERM"
   />
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    changeFormValue: (field, value) => {
        dispatch(change(FORMS_NAME.LOAN_FORM, field, value))
    },
    changeGlobalFormValue: (field, value) => {
        dispatch(change(FORMS_NAME.ACCESS_SEEKER_GLOBAL, field, value))
    },
});
```

So when I console log **term**, I can see it being null initially and then becoming 50.
By that time API call has been made and my payload is missing term

Answer (score 0):

Before making an API call check if `term` is NOT `null`, and then make the API call.

Make use of `useEffect` with the dependency array containing `term` and make the API call through the `useEffect`.